# Quick, self-contained way to see why $\left({{-1}\over p}\right) = 1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be a prime number congruent to $1$ modulo $4$. What is a quick and self-contained way to see why$$\left({{-1}\over p}\right) = 1?$$

Comment: Do you know some basic group theory?

Answer (score 3):

On $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^*=\{1,2, \dotsc, p-1\}$ consider the equivalence relation, defined by $x \sim y$ iff $x=-y$ or $x=y^{-1}$ or $x=-y^{-1}$.

Since $p$ is odd, we have $x \neq -x$, i.e. any equivalence class has $2$ or $4$ elements:

- If $x^2=1$, we have $[x] = \{x,-x\}$
- If $x^2=-1$, we have $[x] = \{x,-x=x^{-1}\}$
- In any other case, we have $[x] = \{x,-x,x^{-1},(-x)^{-1}\}$

We certainly have the equivalence class $\{1,p-1=-1\}$.

$p-1 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ yields, that there will be another equivalence class with $2$ elements. This equivalence class must come from the second case, since the first case occurs only once ($x^2=1$ implies $x=\pm 1$ over a field). This shows that $x^2=-1$ is solvable.

Comment: I think that of the presented choices this method uses the least amount of technology. Translating that to a +1.

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is any odd prime, then by [Wilson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem): $$(p-1)!\equiv 1\cdot 2\cdots\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{p-1}{2}\right)\cdots (-2)(-1)\pmod{p}$$

$$\equiv (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left(\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\right)^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$$

If $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, then all the solutions of $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ are $x\equiv \pm\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\pmod{p}$.

---

Edit: another proof: Let $p$ be prime, $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ and let $g$ be a [primitive root mod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) $p$. Then $\text{ord}_p(g)=p-1$, so $g^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv -1\pmod{p}$. Therefore, all the solutions of $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ are $x\equiv \pm g^{\frac{p-1}{4}}\pmod{p}$.

Comment: This is a good one!

Comment: The proof from your edit is basically the same proof, that Joanpemo already gave.

Comment: @MooS It's similar, but it doesn't use group theory terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose

$$\;p=1\pmod4\implies p-1=0\pmod4\implies \;\text{the cyclic group}\;\;\Bbb F_p^*\;$$
 of order $\;p-1\;$ has a unique subgroup of order $\;4\;$, say $\;T:=\langle x\rangle\;$ , and since

$$\text{ord}\,(x)=4\implies x^2=-1$$

Comment: You use that a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic. I would not call that self-contained.

Comment: @MooS Thank you. And your answer uses equivalence relations and equivalence classes and that a polynomial of degree two can have only two different, at most,  roots over a field. That is as self contained as mine, in my opinion...depending on what the asker knows.

Comment: Wow. You want to tell me, that this result in group theory is more basic than knowledge about equivalence relations? If so, I will delete my answer, since good math is no more appreciated.

Comment: @MooS I didn't say about "good" or "bad" math, but about what is "basic". The question itself is basic undergraduate in my university, and you'd need 1 year or little more to understand it. For me that is basic. Also, you're using, as already commented, that $\;x^2=1\iff x=\pm-1\;$ over a field, which is also basic undergraduate. I'd say that the asker shall ponder and decide. Your answer is fine, I don't think you need to delete it...but that's up to you.

Comment: Sorry for being a little bit harsh there. But nevertheless you should admit, that - basically speaking - you learn $x^2=1 \Longleftrightarrow x = \pm 1$ in high school, when you are about 14 or 15 years old. Of course you only learn it within the context of "usual numbers", but the argument taught in high school is exactly the same you need in the undergraduate context.

When talking about "basic", one should distinguish between concepts, which are completely unkown from a lower point of view and those which are already known before, but taken care of in a "lower language".